# Getting the actual id from where slector works on multiple id

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, form-submit

I'm working with jQuery. I have a Javascript method which works on two selector like this -

```
$('#from1, #form2').submit(function() {
   ....
   .... 

  //is there any way to know the actual id (that is - form1 or form2)
  //for which the submit() method is called
}
```

This is a pretty large method and two of the form (`form1` and `from2`) share almost the same code so that I don't want to write multiple `submit()` method for each form separately. So is there any way to get the actual `id` for which the `submit` method is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(this).attr('id')
```

`$(this)` will point to the `form` that triggered the `submit` event.

This is the common syntax in all the event handlers. `this` will point to the element that triggers an event and `$(this)` will make it a JQuery object so that you can use many built in JQuery syntax on it, just like how we have used `.attr('id')`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the `<form>` elements are the `this` inside of the anonymous method, as they look to be from your (very abridged) posted code, then you can simply use:

```
$('#form1, #form2').submit(function(){
  let formID = this.id;

  // or (expensively, redundantly):
  // formID = $(this).prop('id');
  // or:
  // formID = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

If, however, a child-element of the `<form>` is the `this`, then you can instead use:

```
$('#form1, #form2').submit(function(){
  let formID = this.form.id;
});
```

Note that in the above I've corrected what I presumed to be a typo in the selector, `#from1` has been changed to `#form1`.

Also, as correctly pointed out in the comments, `let` is a relatively new ES6 alternative for declaring variables; if you need to support older browsers you may have to stick with `var` instead.

Comment: Don't forget that `let` is relatively new if you need to support older browsers. http://caniuse.com/#feat=let